# Android 11 Voice search button doesn't show

Tags: android, searchview, android-11

In `Android 11`, when `targetSdk` is set to `30` and voice search is enabled, the microphone icon doesn't show on the `SearchView`. However, it works correctly if `targetSdk` is set to 29.  It works on `Android 10` devices also with `targetSdk 30`.
Is there anything extra which needs to be done for `30`?

**menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**searchable.xml**

```
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hint="Search"
    android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer"/>
```

**MainActivity**

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.search, menu)

        val searchManager = getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE) as SearchManager
        val searchView: SearchView = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).actionView as SearchView
        val searchableInfo = searchManager.getSearchableInfo(componentName)
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateOptionsMenu: ${searchableInfo.voiceSearchEnabled}, ${searchableInfo.voiceSearchLaunchRecognizer}")

        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchableInfo)
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Android 11` doesn't allow checking all the installed applications, so we need to add a `queries` block to allow the app to see the `voice search` app.

Add this in `AndroidManifest.xml` below the `manifest` tag for microphone icon to show up:

```
 <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.speech.action.RECOGNIZE_SPEECH" />
        </intent>
 </queries>
```

[Package visiblility in Android 11](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/package-visibility#set-up-environment)

**Note**: If you get build error(not lint warning) saying `queries element not allowed`, make sure to update build tools version:

[image: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/07/preparing-your-build-for-package-visibility-in-android-11.html]

Image taken from https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/07/preparing-your-build-for-package-visibility-in-android-11.html

Comment: Thanks a lot! This help me to solve the issue!

Comment: Thank you! Google needs to update their SearchView documentation!